# Swift PLUICameraViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Tags: swift, ios8

I have my app in only landscape and with this code i take a picture

```
@IBAction func shootPhoto(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

    if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        noCamera()
    }
}
```

but when I press the button I get this error

> 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PLUICameraViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's documentation [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIImagePickerController):

> IMPORTANT
>
> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
>   class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
>   The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified,
>   with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
>   cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
>   information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
>   and your code.

You have to check Portrait Device Orientation in your targets General settings under Deployment Info.

[image]